# Can template parameters determined at runtime be passed to specialize functions

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

Apologies, I would try this out myself but I won't be near a computer for a while and would like to know if something like the below is possible. I'd like to determine the template param at runtime and eventually pass that to a specialized function.  If not what is the most efficient way to do this?

```
class validate
{
    public:
            template<int x>  
            bool valid();
};


template<> 
bool validate:valid<0>() { return false;}

template<>
bool validate:valid<5>() { return true;}



template <int p>
class Ctx
{
      public:
            bool run() { return _val.template valid<p>();}

    validate _val;   
}

class Handler 
{
     public:

           Handler(const string& str) 
           {
                if(str=="blue")
                  _ctx = new Ctx<1>();
                else if("str = "red")
                  _ctx = new Ctx<5>();
                else
                   _ctx = new Ctx<0>();

           }

           Ctx<int>* getCtx() { return _ctx;}

      private:

           Ctx<int>* _ctx;

};

void main()
{
     //read string from keyboard prompt.. cin >> value;
     Handler h(value);
     Ctx<int>* ctx = h.getCtx();
     bool v = ctx->run();
}
```

Expanding on this, since I will know the range of input values, can I do something like the below (adapted from another question on stackoverflow), essentially expanding the Ctx template for all values and using and array for lookup?  question is will template

bool run(), work for each specialized run function?

```
template <int p>
class Ctx
{
      public:
            template<p> 
            bool run();

}
template<>   //will these work?
bool Ctx<int>::run<5>() { return true; }

template<>   //will these work?
bool Ctx<int>::run<3>() { return false; }


template<int N, int... Ns>
struct ctx_table : ctx_table<N -1, N-1, ,Ns...> {};

template<int... Ns>
struct ctx_table<0,Ns...>
{ 
   static constexpr void (*ctxs<int>[]() = {Ctx<Ns>...};
};

template <int... Ns>
constexpr void (*ctx_table<0,Ns...>::ctxs<int>[sizeof...(ns)]) ();

int main()
{
    cint >> value;
    int val = atoi(value);
    if(val >100) 
        return 0;
    //can I do this?   
    ctx_table<100>::ctxs[val].run();
}
```

Comment: Template parameters are determined at compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use a compile-time construct at run-time. That isn't possible. What you really want is either a polymorphic class or a simple function.

P.S.
You can't specialize a member function template, so the first part of your example (even with correct syntax) isn't correct either.

---

Using a free-standing function would be the best, most performant idea:

```
template<int N>
struct is_valid: public std::false_type{};

template<>
struct is_valid<5>: public std::true_type{};

auto is_valid_str(const std::string &str) -> bool{
    if(str == "blue")
        return is_valid<1>::value;
    else if(str == "red")
        return is_valid<5>::value;
    else
        return false;
}

auto main() -> int{
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;
    std::cout << "valid: " << std::boolalpha << is_valid_str(input) << std::endl;
}
```

but if you *need* dynamic dispatch (you currently don't), use an abstract base class:

```
class base{
    public:
        virtual ~base(){}
        virtual auto run() -> void = 0;
};

template<int N>
class derived: public base{
    public:
        auto run(){ throw std::runtime_error("bad input"); }
};

template<>
class derived<1>: public base{
    public:
        auto run(){ std::cout << "doing work for<1>..." << std::endl; }
};

template<>
class derived<5>: public base{
    public:
        auto run(){ std::cout << "doing work for <5>..." << std::endl; }
};
```

Then put it all together:

```
auto get_dispatch(const std::string &str) -> std::unique_ptr<base>{
    if(str == "blue")
        return new derived<1>{};
    else if(str == "red")
        return new derived<5>{};
    else
        return new derived<0>{};
}

auto main() -> int{
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;
    auto dispatch = get_dispatch(input);
    dispatch->run();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe C++ templates work that way. The calls to the constructors of the `Ctx` class will be resolved at compile time. So the right function you want can be called at runtime. But in general you cannot rely on templates for runtime manipulation. Templates are resolved by the time your code is run

A simple solution would be to have a map of keys to functions and resolve the function calls at runtime based on the parameter passed.